# How to sort a list with possible null empty Object values in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have come across similar posts but not one that addresses my problem.

I have a list of objects that I would like to sort from latest to oldest based on `lastViewDate` value which can be null/empty

The following crashes my app as it is obviously expecting a value for `lastVenueDate` field

`myList.sort((a, b) => b.lastVenueViewDate!.compareTo(a.lastVenueViewDate!));`

I have tried to update my code to this but got stuck.

`myList.sort((a, b) => b.lastVenueViewDate == null ? <what to do here> : b.lastVenueViewDate.compareTo(a.lastVenueViewDate));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a bit more concrete code, if you want nulls to sort *before* all entries with DateTime proper, use something like this:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; // add to pubspec

final one = DateTime(1); // year 1
myList.sortBy((e) => e.lastVenueViewDate ?? one);
```

To have nulls to sort *after*, change "1" to "99999".

This uses the convenient [sortBy](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/ListExtensions/sortBy.html) from package [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection), a first-party package of cool stuff.

(And yes, a full-blown .compareBy can process the nulls specially, but this is easier to understand.)

Comment: learnt something today, that was helpful!

Comment: Can you "accept" my answer then, so I can get meaningless points?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Common is to sort null values first or last in a list compared to defined values. So either return -1 or 1 where you wrote `what to do here`. If both a and b are null, you could e.g. return 0.

Answer (score -1):

After checking the value of the date, if it is null
you can set any **default** value to it.
So that it can be compared with the other values of the list.
This can solve your problem